# Get message from php file?

Tags: php, parameters, get, message

I have an external php file which i send a parameters to it like the following :
http://www.smsws.com/sendsms.php?user=demo&password=demo&numbers=973390000000&sender=hgicom.com&message=test&lang=en

when i go to that link it will show a message if the login is invalid or the number is incorrect, ..etc 
i want to know how to get that message, because based on this message i will do an action in my application. is that possible?

Comment: use `cURL` methods or `file_get_contents()` to get response from URL

Comment: What have you tried? Does it show correctly, when you change the url user and pass to a correct log in combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$msgurl='http://www.smsws.com/sendsms.php?user=demo&password=demo&numbers=973390000000&sender=hgicom.com&message=test&lang=en;
$result=file_get_contents($msgUrl);
switch($result) {
case 'successful':
   echo ' awesome';
   break;
}
```

you may use if statements as well depending on the input sent back

Comment: $result=file_get_contents($msgUrl); 
changed msgUrl to msgurl
capital "U"

Answer (score 1):

```
$url="http://www.smsws.com/sendsms.php?user=demo&password=demo&numbers=973390000000&sender=hgicom.com&message=test&lang=en"
$res=file_get_contents($url);
if($res)
{
     echo "message successfully send";
}
```

Comment: Now the situation changed, i have the URL like that
http://www.smsws.com/?user=demo&password=demo&numbers=973390000000
the file name not shown .. so i used the method that you advise and it worked well in the case that the file shown in the URL, but now id doesn't work ... do you have any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: @Ahmed don't understand your comment. will you clearly say it please.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use cURL to fetch page, and some html parser like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to parse response.

There are plenty of resources how to work with cURL, here is basic one
http://www.higherpass.com/php/Tutorials/Using-Curl-To-Query-Remote-Servers/